# displaying data result from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

i need displaying the company name from the database but this code does not work for me. Please help. Thanks

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include('php/db.php');

   $result = mysql_query("select name from company where company_id = 1");


 echo $result['name'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Yes, let me do some magic to find out what's in your database. Well, where is your `mysql_fetch_array()` by the way?

Comment: my code now seems like this, but without any result:
<?php
// connect to the database
include('php/db.php');
$result = mysql_query("select name from company where company_id= 1 ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
      echo $row['name']."<br>";
}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This One**

```
// connect to the database
include('php/db.php');
$result = mysql_query("select name from company where company_id='1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
      echo $row['name']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: i tried the code, without any results. you can see the result at www.bigbossfood.com/companyname.php
any other idea?

Comment: another you can use mysql_fetch_assoc returns the proper object after that you can store data in to array() after try to display using foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo ""+$row['name'];
   echo "<br>";
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_query` returns an object, you first need to turn the object into an associative array using `mysql_fetch_assoc();`

You can then access elements of that array using the method you have used.

You may want to look at using the `mysqli` functions, as `mysql` functions are depreciated.